# Mysql creating high load average

Tags: mysql

Every few days the load average on my Linux server goes through the roof 10.0+ and mysql is at the top of "top".   Does anyone have an idea of how I can track down where this mysterious load is coming from?

Thanks for any advice.

Chris

Answer (score 3):

When the load average peaks log in to MySql and type command "show processlist". This will give you the queries that MySql is executing currently. From there you can track down the ones that cause you problems.